# Error when using (caret) to train an mlp model

Tags: r, r-caret, mlp

I used caret to train an mlp model with this code.

```
    library(datasets)
    library(MASS)
    library(caret)
    DP = caret::createDataPartition(Boston$medv, p=0.75, list = F)

    train = Boston[DP,]
    test = Boston[-DP,]
    colnames(train) = colnames(Boston)
    colnames(test) = colnames(Boston)

    mlp = caret::train(medv ~., data = Boston, method = "mlp", trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3),
                       tuneGrid = expand.grid(size = 1:3), linOut = T, metric = "RMSE")

    Yp = caret::predict.train(mlp, test[,1:13])
```

I got this error message:

```
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo, : There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

please guys I need to understand why I got this error?

Answer (score 1):

The R squared value for some runs throws NA, you can check the output:

```
set.seed(111)
mlp = caret::train(medv ~., data = Boston, method = "mlp",
trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3),
tuneGrid = expand.grid(size = 1:3), linOut = T, metric = "RMSE")

    mlp$results
  size      RMSE    Rsquared       MAE    RMSESD RsquaredSD     MAESD
1    1  9.152376         NaN  6.640184 0.9213123         NA 0.6877405
2    2 14.353732 0.000965434 12.274448 8.3227673         NA 8.6994894
3    3 12.701064         NaN 10.988850 3.2658958         NA 3.6549478
```

Note even for models that work, your Rsquared is too low. Two problems with the model, 1) your size might be too low, and 2) you don't scale the data, so your predictions give you only one value, and R2 will be total nonsense:

```
Yp = caret::predict.train(mlp, test[,1:13])

table(Yp)
Yp
20.0358009338379 
             125
```

Try something like this:

```
mlp = caret::train(medv ~., data = Boston, method = "mlp",
trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3),
preProcess = c("center","scale"),
tuneGrid = expand.grid(size = 3:5), linOut = T, metric = "RMSE")

mlp
Multi-Layer Perceptron 

506 samples
 13 predictor

Pre-processing: centered (13), scaled (13) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (3 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 337, 338, 337 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  size  RMSE      Rsquared   MAE     
  3     7.926669  0.3291762  5.619198
  4     6.976707  0.4913297  5.130273
  5     6.894459  0.5188481  5.040821
```